# Call graph of C++ program under Eclipse / Ubuntu 13.10 x64

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, call-graph, systemtap

I would like to draw the call graph of a C++ program under Eclipse / Ubuntu 13.10 x64.

I have installed SystemTap and am able to launch the "initial testing" properly.

But when I try to get the call graph of my program, I obtain:

- *bad fd number* if I right-click on my project -> Profiling tools -> function callgraph
- *Output file broken* if I launch the profiling from Run menu

How to do this properly work on Ubuntu ?